# How do I access Azure Blob Storage with DeviceCode Authentication?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I can't seem to find out how I can create a BlobServiceClient using the AuthenticationResult from a DeviceCode AuthenticationResult.

Any idea on how to do this - I want to download files from BlobStorage to an IoT device during configuration so the technician authenticates using a DeviceCode which needs to authorize the application to be able to access the BlobStorage.

EDIT:
Added existing code.

My understanding is that one has to make separate requests for AccessTokens for different resources but that one can use the "Refresh Token" from the first Auth Request in subsequent requests to avoid having to ask the user to authenticate a second time.

The code below works find for getting the IOTC access token but there doesn't seem to be any refresh token or any API for making a second call to get the access token for Blob Storage.

So is this even possible and if so how does one get access tokens for multiple resources without multiple user interactions ?

Bear in mind this is using DeviceCode authentication because there is no Browser available on the device.  I am assuming that shouldn't matter.

```
public class Constants
 {
     // Need to be replaced after running CLI
     public const string ClientApplicationId = "app-id";

     // Need to be replaced after running CLI
     public const string TenantId = "tenant-id";

     // Need to be replaced after running CLI
     public const string AppName = "registered-desktop-app-name";

     public const string ApiVersion = "2022-07-31";

     public const string DeviceTemplateId = "dtmi:modelDefinition:e2eStandard;1";

     public static string[] IOTCScopes = new[] { "https://apps.azureiotcentral.com/.default" };

     public static string[] StorageScopes = new[] { "https://storage.azure.com/.default" };
 }

       AuthenticationResult? IOTCAuthResult;
       AuthenticationResult? BlobSAuthResult;
       DeviceCredentials? deviceCreds;

       // Authenticate using DeviceCode
       // Get access tokens for IOTC and BlobStorage
       public async Task LoginAzureAD()
       {
           
           IOTCAuthResult = await GetATokenForIOTCWithDeviceCode();

           if (IOTCAuthResult != null)
           {
               AuthInstruction = $"Authenticated user {IOTCAuthResult.Account.Username}.";

           }
           else
           {
               AuthInstruction = "Error no authentication, try again or check with you administrator.";
               
               return;
           }

            // Now get access for Storage account
            // HOW DO WE DO THIS WITHOUT ANOTHER AUTHENTICATION PROMPT ?
            // Where is the RefreshToken and how are we supposed to use it 
            // to avoid another UI interaction with the user 

           BlobSAuthResult = await GetATokenForBlobSWithDeviceCode();

           if (BlobSAuthResult != null)
           {
               AuthInstruction = $"Authenticated storage user {BlobSAuthResult.Account.Username}.";
           }
           else
           {
               AuthInstruction = "Error no storage authentication, try again or check with you administrator.";
           }
       }


      async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetATokenForIOTCWithDeviceCode()
      {
          IPublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                  .Create(Constants.ClientApplicationId)
                  .WithAuthority(authority)
                  .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                  .Build();
          cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

          var accounts = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();

          // All AcquireToken* methods store the tokens in the cache, so check the cache first
          try
          {
              return await pca.AcquireTokenSilent(Constants.Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                  .ExecuteAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
          }
          catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
          {
              // No token found in the cache or Azure AD insists that a form interactive auth is required (e.g. the tenant admin turned on MFA)
              // If you want to provide a more complex user experience, check out ex.Classification
              Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");
              return await AcquireByDeviceCodeAsync(pca);
          }
      }

    private async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireByDeviceCodeAsync(IPublicClientApplication pca)
      {
          try
          {
               

              var result = await pca.AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode(Constants.Scopes,
                  deviceCodeResult =>
                  {
                      // This will print the message on the console which tells the user where to go sign-in using
                      // a separate browser and the code to enter once they sign in.
                      // The AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode() method will poll the server after firing this
                      // device code callback to look for the successful login of the user via that browser.
                      // This background polling (whose interval and timeout data is also provided as fields in the
                      // deviceCodeCallback class) will occur until:
                      // * The user has successfully logged in via browser and entered the proper code
                      // * The timeout specified by the server for the lifetime of this code (typically ~15 minutes) has been reached
                      // * The developing application calls the Cancel() method on a CancellationToken sent into the method.
                      //   If this occurs, an OperationCanceledException will be thrown (see catch below for more details).
                        
                        // DISPLAY the auth instructions to the user 
                      this.AuthInstruction = deviceCodeResult.Message;

                      return Task.FromResult(0);
                  }).ExecuteAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

                
              return result;
          }

          // TODO: handle or throw all these exceptions depending on your app
          catch (MsalServiceException ex)
          {
              // Kind of errors you could have (in ex.Message)
              Debug.WriteLine($"MsalServiceException: {ex.Message}");
              // AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.
              // Mitigation: as explained in the message from Azure AD, the authoriy needs to be tenanted. you have probably created
              // your public client application with the following authorities:
              // https://login.microsoftonline.com/common or https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations

              // AADSTS90133: Device Code flow is not supported under /common or /consumers endpoint.
              // Mitigation: as explained in the message from Azure AD, the authority needs to be tenanted

              // AADSTS90002: Tenant <tenantId or domain you used in the authority> not found. This may happen if there are
              // no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription administrator.
              // Mitigation: if you have an active subscription for the tenant this might be that you have a typo in the
              // tenantId (GUID) or tenant domain name.
          }
          catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
          {
              // If you use a CancellationToken, and call the Cancel() method on it, then this *may* be triggered
              // to indicate that the operation was cancelled.
              // See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads
              // for more detailed information on how C# supports cancellation in managed threads.

              Debug.WriteLine($"OperationCanceledException: {ex.Message}");
          }
          catch (MsalClientException ex)
          {
              // Possible cause - verification code expired before contacting the server
              // This exception will occur if the user does not manage to sign-in before a time out (15 mins) and the
              // call to `AcquireTokenWithDeviceCode` is not cancelled in between
              Debug.WriteLine($"MsalClientException: {ex.Message}");
          }
          return null;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so half my problem was mixing Microsoft.Identify and Azure.Identity !!

Here is what I ended up with, which is much simpler.

```
      AuthenticationRecord? IOTCAuthResult;
      DeviceCodeCredential? deviceCodeCreds;
      DeviceCredentials? deviceCreds;
      AccessToken IOTCAccessToken;
      public async Task LoginAzureAD()
      {
          cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
     
          var deviceCodeOptions = new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions
          {
              ClientId = Constants.ClientApplicationId,
              TenantId = Constants.TenantId,
              AuthorityHost = new Uri(authority),
              DeviceCodeCallback = (code, cancellation) =>
              {
                  // This results in the message being displayed to the user
                  AuthInstruction = code.Message;
                  return Task.CompletedTask;
              }
          };
          await SetState(InstallState.WaitingForAuthentication);
          IsWaitingForAuth = true;
        
          try
          {
              deviceCodeCreds = new DeviceCodeCredential(deviceCodeOptions);
              IOTCAuthResult = await deviceCodeCreds.AuthenticateAsync(new TokenRequestContext(Constants.Scopes), cancellationTokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    
              AuthInstruction = $"Authenticated user {IOTCAuthResult.Username}";
              // Create a secret client using the DefaultAzureCredential
              var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://myvault.azure.vaults.net/"), deviceCodeCreds);
    
              IOTCAccessToken = await deviceCodeCreds.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(Constants.Scopes));
    
              IsWaitingForAuth = false;
              await SetState(InstallState.Authenticated);
    
          } catch (Exception ex)
          {
              AuthInstruction = $"Error no authentication, try again or check with you administrator.: {ex.Message}";
              IsWaitingForAuth = false;
              await SetState(InstallState.Ready);
          }
      }

       public async Task<bool> IoTCentralGetDevice()
       {
           if (Id.Length < 8)
           {
               eventLog.WriteEntry($"ID is too short: {Id}");
               return false;
           }
           string deviceId = Id;

           var previousState = State;
           await SetState(InstallState.IDDownloading);

           cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
           // Check if the device has already registered !!

           using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
           httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", IOTCAccessToken.Token);

           using var centralClient = new AzureIoTCentral(httpClient, true);
           centralClient.Subdomain = Constants.AppName;
           centralClient.ApiVersion = Constants.ApiVersion;


           Debug.WriteLine("Query the device");
           var devices = new Devices(centralClient);

           Device device = await devices.GetAsync(deviceId, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

}

       private async Task<bool> DownloadAzureFiles()
       {
           //var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
           var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://xxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net"), deviceCodeCreds);

           var container = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(credsContainerName);

 }
```